# Chamar método com parâmetro com elementos de vetor definidos

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos, método

Boa noite!

Eu criei um método que calcula os elementos de um vetor e faz a média geral, porém não estou conseguindo chamá-lo no método main. 
PS: sou iniciante.

Agradeço a ajuda desde já!

```
package proj04;

public class media {

    private static double mediatotal;
    private static double[] notasAlunos = {10, 5, 7, 8, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6, 8, 4, 6};

    public static double getMediatotal() {
        return mediatotal;
    }
    public static void setMediatotal(double mediatotal) {
        media.mediatotal = mediatotal;
    }

        public static double mediat(double notasAlunos[]) {

            double soma = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                soma = (soma + notasAlunos[i]) / 15;
                mediatotal = soma;
            }
            return soma;
        }               
    }

package proj04;

public class exe4main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double mediavar;
        media mediaturma = new media();

        System.out.println( mediaturma.getMediatotal());            
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Não achei o erro no seu código, porem deixo algumas dicas.

Normalmente nome de classe começa com letra Maiúscula.

As funções e variáveis da sua `class media` estão todas `static` então você não precisa criar uma instancia dela `new media()` você pode acessar direto pela classe Ex. `media.getMediatotal()`.

Na `main` você esta dando print no retorno da `getMediatotal`
que neste momento ainda é nula.

Você definiu `private static double[] notasAlunos` como **private** então você não vai conseguir acessar ele fora da classe `media` e pelo visto você quer passar ela para a função `mediat`, opções:

1. Trocar o `private` para `public` ou deixar sem nenhum dos dois, sem nenhum dos dois vai funcionar por estarem no mesmo `package`.
2. Não receber `notasAlunos` por parametro na função `mediat` acessar de dentro dela.

Fiz algumas alterações no seu código e coloquei ele formatado para rodar no **Ideone** [veja ele em execução](https://ideone.com/eLCWWa)

```
class Exe4main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) // throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        double mediavar;

        Media.mediat( Media.notasAlunos );
        System.out.println( Media.getMediatotal() ); 
    }
}

class Media {

    private static double mediatotal;
    public static double[] notasAlunos = {10, 5, 7, 8, 6, 8, 10, 9, 7, 6, 7, 6, 8, 4, 6};

    public static double getMediatotal() {
        return mediatotal;
    }
    public static void setMediatotal(double mediatotal) {
        Media.mediatotal = mediatotal;
    }

    public static double mediat(double notasAlunos[]) {

        double soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            soma = (soma + notasAlunos[i]) / 15;
            mediatotal = soma;
        }
        return soma;
    }               
}
```

---

Uma forma de acessar ou alterar uma variável `private` seria criar métodos **get** e **set** 'public' para essa variável, ou seja, da mesma forma que você fez para a variável `mediatotal`, veja outro exemplo abaixo

```
class Media{

    private static double[] minhaVar;

    public static void setMinhaVar( double[] novoValor ){

        minhaVar = novoValor;

    }

    public static double[] getMinhaVar( ) {

        return minhaVar;

    }
}
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado pelas dicas, vou aplicar nos próximos exercícios!!!! O que eu estou percebendo é que há um erro de lógica nesse meu código. A minha intenção é somar os elementos do vetor notasAlunos e dividir por 15 (fazer a média). O código do jeito que está até compila, mas retorna o resultado errado...

Comment: Se você tirar o parênteses deste cálculo `(soma + notasAlunos[i]) / 15;` deve resolver, porém eu faria a soma dentro do `for` e fora dele faria a divisão por 15

Comment: Agora consegui aplicando as suas dicas!!! Eu só queria saber como seria se eu quisesse acessar o vetor notasAlunos como private? Aliás, eu agradeço muito pela sua didática e inclusive por ter melhorado o código, vc demonstra ser um ótimo profissional.

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo de **get** e **set**, que uma forma de acessar e alterar variáveis **private**.